# Politically incorrect tag: North-Korea -> DPRK

Tags: support, tags, retagging

The country commonly called [north-korea](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/north-korea) is actually the "Democratic People's Republic of Korea". That is too long for a tag, which only allows 35 characters. The proper shorthand would be DPRK. As such, the tag North Korea should be swapped to [dprk](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dprk) or, if a mod can overwrite tag length, to [democratic-peoples-republic-of-korea](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/democratic-peoples-republic-of-korea)

Comment: By "Politically incorrect" do you mean that calling the country "North Korea" is considered by typical members of polite society to be offensive, or do you merely mean that it is not the (Orwellian) term by which that country's regime wishes it to be called?

Comment: @feetwet political correct as in "That is the proper term of the political entity, as understood by the UN" - their office in the UN building is the "Permanent Mission of the Democratic People's Republic of Korea to the United Nations"

Answer (score 5):

### No

We use [united-states](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) not the United States of America, [united-kingdom](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-kingdom) not the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland, [australia](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/australia) not the Commonwealth of Australia, [south-africa](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/south-africa) not the Republic of South Africa.

Commonly used and well understood names are fine.

Comment: Yes but north doesn’t even feature in the official name, and it is politically loaded to the extent that some political activists prefer to refer to Korea’s north so as to maintain recognition that it is one nation which is divided by partial western subjugation. At the very least I think that they should be made synonyms in one way or another.

Comment: We don't yet have any questions about it, but once we do, clearly we should use [tag:republic-east-of-the-uruguay].